# Homebrew installation in mac is giving error

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew

I want to install homebrew on my mac system but i am not able to install. Installation process is giving me error.

```
error: could not lock config file /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/config: Permission denied
fatal: could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'
Failed during: git init -q
```

I have tried below command to install homebrew

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score 23):

Remove the current installation with:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew
```

and install it again without using [sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Answer (score 3):

the location have change so now use this :

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

and install again with :

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```